# Sending values as parameters to .net core web api

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

In my api application, I send parameters via "controller" as follows.

For example; I am sending fields like "companyId", "userName" as parameters. But I don't always send "userName" field or "companyId" field full. So it can happen when I send it empty. I want it to fetch with "like" when I send it blank. can i do this?

```
 public async Task<List<Inventory>> GetInventoryList(int companyId, string userName, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        IQueryable<Inventory> query;
        query = _context.Inventories
               .Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId)
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate);

        int totalCount = query.Count();

        var response = await query.Skip((pageSize * (page - 1)))
            .Take(pageSize)
            .Select(x => new Inventory()
            {
                CompanyId = x.CompanyId,


                CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate,
                Barcode = x.Barcode,
                BrandId = x.BrandId,
                BusinessCode = x.BusinessCode,
                CategoryId = x.CategoryId,
                CategorySubId = x.CategorySubId,
                Id = x.Id,
                Imei = x.Imei,
                InventoryDate = x.InventoryDate,
                InvoiceDate = x.InvoiceDate,
                Mac = x.Mac,
                ModelId = x.ModelId,
                Name = x.Name,
                SerialNumber = x.SerialNumber,
                Status = x.Status,
                Responsible = x.Responsible,
                TotalCount = totalCount,
                UpdatedDate = x.UpdatedDate
            }).ToListAsync();
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: can you explain these two sentences a bit more "So it can happen when I send it empty. I want it to fetch with "like" when I send it blank." i dont understand what you mean here

Comment: My english is bad, sorry.
Let me say this briefly. I am sending companyId, userName, page, pageSize parameters.
Sometimes when I send "username, page, pageSize", no data is coming, so it doesn't search.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71641741/dynamic-filtering-using-linq-in-asp-net-core   I want to do a filter like here

Comment: Use `if-else` conditions to generate your `response` query. `if(string.IsNotNullOrEmpty(userName){ // use LIKE} else { // something else }`